# Open files in specific directory based on inputed file name by user

Tags: perl, file-io, directory, user-input

I am trying to open a file located at `\\\server\folder\folder\folder\filename.csv` based on user input for the file name.  The file will always be a csv file, but the name will be different based on departments.  The directory will always be the same, however it is not the directory Perl resides in.

I have been having issues trying to open the file.  I have tried to make 2 variables, 1 for the directory and 1 for the file name, but I just get errors thrown when I try to open `$directory\\$FileName`.  I have tried to do an open statement with the directory hard coded in and the file name a variable, but Perl thinks the variable is part of the file name (which makes sense).  Is this even possible?

After I have the file open, I have code to run which will edit the file itself (this works fine) and then I want to save the file in a new location.  This new location is the same as the directory, but I want to add another folder level to it and then the same file name.  Kind of a "before change" file location and an "after change" file location.

```
print "What is your FULL file name going to be with extension included?";
my $fileInName = <>; 
my $@dirpath= '\\\\Server\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Folder4\\Sorted_files\\';
my $Excel = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application') || 
    Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', 'Quit'); 
my $Book = $Excel->Workbooks->Open($directory $file); 
my $Sheet = $Book->Worksheets(1);
$Sheet->Activate();
```

That is the code I have now.  I tried the following as well:

```
my $@dirpath= '\\\\server\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\call_folder4\\Sorted_files\\$fileName';
```

Of course I received the "file cannot be found error:
My file open works great if I hard code the entire path name, but I do not want to have 25 seperate scripts out there with the only difference being a file name.

Comment: Are you using single quotes around your path? Please post some Code. Then only something can happen..

Comment: Show actual code that demonstrates the problem. `$directory\$FileName` is not valid Perl. `'$directory\$FileName'` and `"$directory\$FileName"` are also incorrect.

Comment: @Amy Use the "edit" button and add the code to your question. Dont post code in the comments.

Comment: I tried this as well
<code>
my $@dirpath= '\\\\Server\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Folder4\\Sorted_files\\$fileName';
</code>
<p>As expected it returned file not found error.</p>

Comment: SORRY - for code in comments - I will correct....

Answer (score 0):

Use `file::spec` module.  It's portable and you don't have to worry about escaping slash characters in your path (UPDATE:  mostly true, but in this case, you still need to escape the server reference, as shown below, in the assignment to `@dirpath`).

For example:

```
use File::Spec::Functions;

# get users file from the cmd line arg
my $usersfile = $ARGV[0];

my @dirpath = qw/\\\server folder folder folder/;
my $filepath = catfile(@dirpath,$userfile);

# test existence
die "file does not exist" unless(-e $filepath);
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add some sigils to your variables.

Comment: Thanks!  I've been writing Python lately :-)

Comment: Is `c` suppose to represent the volume? Cause I don't see any use of `catpath` in there, and the volume is actually `\\server\folder` according to the OP.

Comment: @David `$dirpath` is probably meant to be `@dirpath`, since you assign a list to it. Or you meant to write `qq/c some path/`.

Comment: Merely a placeholder, not literal.  OP can use any valid path here.

Comment: Not correctly, he can't. Again, there's no mention of `catpath` in your code.

Comment: @David A good idea is to test the code before you post it. =P

Comment: @ikegami I think you mean `catdir`, but thats not necessary. Both path and file are captured in `catfile`.

Comment: no, I meant `catpath`. Valid: `catpath($vol, catdir('', @dir_path), $file);` -or- `catfile(catpath($vol, catdir('', @dir_path)), $file);`

Comment: @ikegami for a network path (e.g. `\\server\folder`) that lacks a `volume` reference it doesn't appear that `catpath` provides any benefit.  In fact the documentation says `Under Unix, $volume is ignored, and directory and file are concatenated.`  Obviously, this refers to Unix, but I think it could be more generalized to any reference that does not contain a volume.  In this case, `catpath` behaves more or less like `catdir`.

Comment: A path that starts with `\\server\share` does not lack of volume. That is the volume.

Comment: Thank you - I will research the File::Specific and catpath as these are 100% new to me.  Thanks again for suggestions to get me moving in the right direction!

Comment: (This just goes to show why much better [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path::Class) was created to replace File::Spec)

Comment: @ikegami Hmmm... that's interesting.  I'll have to try that.  I notice that it still wraps `File::Spec`, though, so I guess it still shares some functionality.

Comment: @David, hum, if it didn't share the same functionality (path manipulation), it wouldn't be a suitable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $@dirpath= '\\Server\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Sorted_files\';
my $Book = $Excel->Workbooks->Open($directory $file);
```

doesn't even compile. It should be:

```
my $dirpath = '\\\\Server\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Sorted_files';
my $Book = $Excel->Workbooks->Open("$dirpath\\$file");
```